# How to import Library into Vue3 project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

could someone help me import a library to my vue3 project so that I can use it in all components?...

I'am trying to import 'moments.js' to my project

- Its installed with npm
- in my 'main.js' (entry) I import it like:

```
import { createApp } from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue"
import moment from "moment"
const app = createApp(App)
app.use (moment)
app.mount("#app")
```

but when I try to `console.log(this.moment)` from another component I get errors that `this.moment` is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone stumbling onto this post. I changed the code to:

```
import { createApp } from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue"
import moment from "moment"
const app = createApp(App)
app.provide("moment", moment)
app.mount("#app")
```

inside other components:

```
export default {
   inject: ["moment"],
// Other code can now use "moment"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind moment as a global property on the Vue instance by during the `created` lifecycle hook in the like manner.

```js
const { createApp } = require('vue');
import App from "./App.vue";
import moment from 'moment';

const MomentPlugin = function (Vue, options) {
  Vue.mixin({
    created: function () {
      this.moment = moment
    }
  })
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(MomentPlugin).mount("#app");
```

`moment` function is then available in template context or anywhere the Vue instance is available in scope.

Comment: This literally saved me hours of work, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`app.use()` is for adding Vue plugins to the app. It should be possible to convert Moment.js to a plugin - see ["Writing a plugin" in the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) but it shouldn't be necessary.

You can just import moment.js in any component where you want to use it and the bundling process will make sure that the code is not duplicated anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will be using this library in a lot of components, importing it into each component seems like a bad way to go.

Comment: @babis95 It is exactly the way to go. It makes each module work independent of each other. You don't have to assume moment magically exists because the app inserts it into the environment somewhere - you explicitly import it in every script file that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment
as it is vue-specific. It is a wrapper for moment.
Check the Readme file also for instructions.
https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMoment from "vue-moment"
Vue.use(VueMoment));
```

Your case

```
import { createApp } from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue"
import VueMoment from "vue-moment"
const app = createApp(App)
app.use (VueMoment)
app.mount("#app")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried importing vue-moment but I get an 'Object.defineProperties called on non-object' error. I tried on my current project as well as in a newly created one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment like this in any component.

```
methods: {
  moment: function () {
    return moment();
  }
},
```

Comment: With my current import when I try your solution in `app.vue` i get 'moment` is not defined